# truncate ToolStripStatusLabel instead of hiding it

Tags: .net, winforms, truncation, statusstrip, toolstripstatuslabel

I have a StatusStrip control on a form. This control contains only one child control - it is ToolStripStatusLabel. When the text is too large, then nothing is displayed. I would prefer to display at least something instead of nothing. What should I do with ToolStripStatusLabel to display part of text even if the whole text doesn't fit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting the Spring property to true:

```
toolStripStatusLabel1.Spring = true;
```

or as Hans pointed out, you can set the [ToolStripLayoutStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstriplayoutstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
statusStrip1.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Flow;
```

Comment: Changing the strip's LayoutStyle to Flow keeps the text left-aligned.

Comment: with statusStrip1.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Flow;
 also set statusStrip1.AutoSize= false; 
 To make sure that status bar size is fixed (this is what standard applications follow)